# Help with this two variable limit.

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

*Determine if the limit exists:*

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,1)} \frac{1}{x^2+y-1}$$

Based on previous exercises, I'm suppose to prove the inexistence of the limit showing that the limit is different when taking different paths. I just can't figure out what paths to take.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: converging along $(h,1)$, $h\to 0$ you get $\lim_{h\to 0}1/h^2=+\infty$. Converging along $(0,1-h)$ ($h\to 0^+$) you get $\lim_{h\to 0^+}1/(-h)=-\infty$.